# Using IBAction with NSArray in Page Control

Tags: ios, nsstring, ibaction

With TableView, you can use do this

```
if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1 + 1"]) {
lyricstext.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent      mollis fringilla tempus. Vestibulum nec erat in diam volutpat lacinia non sit amet est. 
Phasellus a sagittis tellus, eget feugiat tortor."}
```

I'm wondering how to do this with NSArray! I have this:

```
- (NSArray *) arrayWithImages{
return @[
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/nnReaaJwloI/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/i41qWJ6QjPI/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ag0hsUf9V7Q/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VBmMU_iwe6U/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/FHp2KgyQUFk/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KaasJ44O5lI/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ob7vObnFUJc/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/XWCwc1_sYMY/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PGc9n6BiWXA/hqdefault.jpg",
        @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/2XY3AvVgDns/hqdefault.jpg"
                    ];}
```

How do I have a different hyperlink (IBAction) for example, if the image returned is different?

Comment: Are you trying to cycle through an array of image links?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying so fast :-) Yes I am. I'm using page control, this one in particular! https://github.com/kimar/KIImagePager | I'm able to change the caption but I'm not sure how to do that with a button.

Comment: I posted an answer detailing how you could go through each img link in the array. Let me know if I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish what I follow you're trying to do, I recommend the following.

```
// In your nameOfViewController.h add these two variables as shown:

@interface nameOfViewController
{
    NSArray *imgsArray;
    NSArray *linksToVideos;
    NSString *currentVideoLink;
    int position;
}

// In your nameOfViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // So you'll start at the first image in array
    position = 0;

    // actually initialize your array
    imgsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    linksToVideos = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    currentVideoLink = [[NSString alloc] init];

    // Start currentVideoLink with first video 
    currentVideoLink = @"http://www.youtube.com";
    imgsArray =  @[
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/nnReaaJwloI/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/i41qWJ6QjPI/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ag0hsUf9V7Q/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VBmMU_iwe6U/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/FHp2KgyQUFk/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KaasJ44O5lI/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ob7vObnFUJc/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/XWCwc1_sYMY/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PGc9n6BiWXA/hqdefault.jpg",
    @"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/2XY3AvVgDns/hqdefault.jpg"];

// Array of links that I speak of below
linksToVideos = @[@"url/to/I_Care", @"url/to/I_Was_Here", @"url/to/schoolin_life", @"etc..."];

}
```

The delegate method below is called every time the next image appears. Inside it, the value of index corresponds to the position of the image in your images array. With this information you can use an array of links (to your videos) that correspond with each image to correctly bring up the video of the image. For example, the value of imgsArray[0] (an array for your images) is I Care by Kelly Rowland, which is why when this image displays imagePager:didScrollToIndex:] 0 in the output console. Simply taking this value and applying it to an array of corresponding links will give you the correct link.

```
- (void)imagePager:(KIImagePager *)imagePager didScrollToIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

   currentVideoLink = linksToVideos[index];

}

- (IBAction)watchVideo
{
    // Present video with link currently in currentVideoLink, will open in Safari

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentVideoLink]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to reply. I think you may have misunderstood something :( The images are already linked up right, they change every 5.5s or you can swipe to go to the next one. I'm want to link up a button in every view to YouTube, but a different youtube for everyone. Here's a picture of what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/Oxv2wwJ.png :)

Comment: When you swipe, are you pushing a new view controller onto the screen? Or is it just video that changes?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your wanting an IBAction method.

Comment: To answer your first question, the screenshot of the video changes. Here's a gif of it: http://i.imgur.com/m9M4Xag.gif  / Second question, the IBAction is link to "watch video." Now I'm wondering how to make the hyerlink different based on whatever video screenshot is shown, or title or video. Does that make sense?

Comment: I follow what you're trying to do now. But it's difficult to help with so little information. You should post more code. Start off with the code you have in your IBAction method.

Comment: Thank you for all your patience :) Is it okay to share the .zip of the files? If yes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bsfjdoorykdbim3/KIImagePager-master.zip | The caption (referenced as NSString) in KIViewController.m and the images are all put in place by the custom class of the scrollview which is KIImagePager.m - I'm trying to link the "Watch Video" just like the captions, which changes based on the view. I want "Watch Video" to be linked to the video of the screenshot in the view- Does that make sense? :(

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're trying to do. I just wanted to see how you were trying to do it. I'll check out your link shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd be waiting for your reply :)

Comment: Sorry. That init method was only to show you to initialize your app. Place the code from it in viewDidLoad. I updated my answer to show this.

Comment: All done. How do I replace the already exciting images that were previous listed - (NSArray *) arrayWithImages
{ with the ones in imgsArray? Sorry for all the questions, first time doing this!

Comment: Erase everything that you have in arrayWithImages: and add return imgsArray;

Comment: Yay! I was about to successful return imgarray :-) Thank you for all your help, you've been awesome. The links don't work though. Here's the code now: http://i.imgur.com/RIkBgAX.png - Do I have to add a button or are the links linked to the pictures?

Comment: The only valid link that you have is the one at linksToVideos[0]. So only the first image will load a video. Where are you calling for a video to load from linksToVideos[0]? I don't see any code with you doing so.

Comment: You're supposed to set your currentVideoLink value in didScrollToIndex: not didSelectImageAtIndex:. See code for details.

Comment: Before I tried this, when it gets to the fourth in the array, the app crashes and reason is "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'" | Here's what the code looks like now: http://i.imgur.com/10eCzxj.png

Comment: It tells you that because you only have four links in your array of video links. The program is saying that you are trying to access the linksOfVideos[4] when your array only goes up to linksOfVideos[3]. Also, I still don't see where you are setting the video to your currentVideoLink.

Comment: Refer to the answer above to see what I mean by currentVideoLink.

Comment: You were right :-) No more errors! Now, the problem is getting the links to do work. How do I call the current video? Where do I put in the code? http://i.imgur.com/y62H9zz.png

Comment: You'll put the code in the watchVideo method if it's the method associated with your watch video button. I was actually wondering is what kind of view are you using to display the YouTube video in. Is it going to be in your webview?

Comment: Like this? http://imgur.com/AEQKm8q | Also, I haven't thought about that yet, I think I'm gonna have them open in a webview but I haven't figured that out so they may just open in safari. This has turned out to be a really long discussion, sorry for taking up all your time. When I figure it all out, I may cry lol

Comment: I added code in the answer showing how your watchVideo method should look.

Comment: There aren't enough words to thank you enough. Thank you so so so so so so so so much. It works, perfectly. I appreciate all the time you put into answering me! You're awesome.